# How to send the value of the clicked button in a form to an Ajax function in Dango

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send the value of the button clicked in my html form to the Ajax function, when I do that my form is sending only the value of the first button(Add) even when I click the second button(Delete). What changes should I have to do so the form sends only the value of the clicked button.

my .html file

```
<form action="{% url 'supervisor:manageproject' %}" id="my_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="project_id", value={{project.id}}>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="projectName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Project Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="project" class="form-control-plaintext" id="projectName" value="{{project.project_name}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6>Manage the employees list:</h6>
    <p>Check the boxes to remove employees:</p>

    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-6" >
          <table class="table" id = "change_form1">
            {% for employee in employees_could_add.all %}
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees_inproject" value="{{employee.id}}"> {{employee}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor%}
            <tr>
              <td><button  class="btn btn-primary"  name="Action" value = "Add" type="submit">Add Employees</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <table class="table" id = "change_form2">
          {% for employee in project.employees.all %}
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees" value="{{employee.id}}"> {{employee}}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor%}
          <tr>
            <td><button  class="btn btn-danger"  name="Action" value="delete" type="submit">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

my ajax-call.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("hi")

   $('#my_form').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
           data: $(this).serialize() + '&perform='+$('button').val(), // get the form data
           type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
           dataType: "json",
           url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
           success: function(data){
                d = data
                console.log(data);
                //if ($('button').val() == 'Add'){
                  text = ''
                  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(d["data"].employees_could_add).length; i++) {
                    text += '<tr>'
                    text += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="employees_inproject" value=" '
                    text +=  data['data'].employees_could_add[i].id + '">'
                    text += data['data'].employees_could_add[i].emp_name + '</td></tr>'
                  }
                  text += '<tr><td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="perform" value = "Add" type="submit">Add Employees</button></td></tr>'
                  document.getElementById("change_form1").innerHTML = text
                  text = ''
                  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(d["data"].employees_inproject).length; i++){
                      text += '<tr> <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees" value="'
                      text += data['data'].employees_inproject[i].id + '">'
                      text += data['data'].employees_inproject[i].emp_name + '</td></tr>'
                  }
                  text += '<tr><td><button class="btn btn-danger" name="perform" value="delete" type="submit">Delete</button></td>'
                  document.getElementById("change_form2").innerHTML = text

              //  }else{

              //  }

            },
            error:function(data){
                    console.log('error')
                    console.log(data)
             }
       });
       return false;
   });
   });
```

Comment: instead of making an event for the form submit, make an event for the button clicks themselves and track `$(this).val()`

Comment: Or, you could try: `$('#my_form').submit(function(event)` then check if `event.target` exists with the button context that you want.